# Inference with union of function and object

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have the following types:

```
interface RequestActionMeta<Data, TransformedData> {
  getData?: (data: Data, currentData: TransformedData) => TransformedData;
  [extraProperty: string]: any;
}

export type RequestAction<Data = any, TransformedData = Data> = {
  type: string;
  request: any | any[];
  meta?: RequestActionMeta<Data, TransformedData>;
};

export function createQuery<
  Data = any,
  TransformedData = Data
>(
  name: string,
  requestConfig: any | ((...params: any[]) => any),
  metaConfig?:
    | ((...params: any[]) => RequestActionMeta<Data, TransformedData>)
    | RequestActionMeta<Data, TransformedData>,
): (...params: any[]) => RequestAction<Data, TransformedData>;
```

Generally it works ok, for example:

```
const fetchAnimals = createQuery<
  { id: string; title: string },
  { id: string; name: string }
>('FETCH_ANIMALS', () => ({ url: '/animals' }), {
  getData: data => ({ id: data.id, name1: '1' }),
});
```

would complain because `getData` response doesn't have `name` attribute.

Unfortunately it doesn't work for meta callback (I will need this to make this type compatible with variables later), for example:

```
const fetchAnimals = createQuery<
  { id: string; title: string },
  { id: string; name: string }
>(
  'FETCH_ANIMALS',
  () => ({ url: '/animals' }),
  () => ({
    getData: data => ({ id: data.id, name1: '1' }),
  }),
);
```

won't show similar error.

I suspect this has something to do with using not Discriminating Unions, because below type will suddenly work:

```
export function createQuery<
  Data = any,
  TransformedData = Data
>(
  name: string,
  requestConfig: any | ((...params: any[]) => any),
  metaConfig?: (...params: any[]) => RequestActionMeta<Data, TransformedData>,
): (...params: any[]) => RequestAction<Data, TransformedData>;
```

which really is a proof this is not about callback, it is about union.

Any ideas how to make this work? I experimented a little with conditional types, but without success either.

Comment: It's actually the `[extraProperty: string]: any;` that's screwing it up!  I don't have a solution (yet) other than to remove this.  What is it needed for?

Comment: Any object whatsoever without a `getData` property will be assignable to a `RequestActionMeta<Data, TransformedData>`, so that's why you don't get an error with that function. At the very least you need to prevent functions from being compatible with that type if you want to see an error on a particular function. Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/wXRKom) work for your use cases?    If so I'll write it up; if not, please elaborate on what fails.

Comment: @LindaPaiste Indeed, I will just remove it, as a last resort I will just create a dedicated key like `extraArgs: any` if needed!

Comment: @jcalz thx! I thing this is also connected with Linda's answer, function is an object after all! Your solution is very interesting and I could use it if preserving `[extraProperty: string]: any;`